# Programmatically working with color gradients

Tags: python, colors, gimp, gradient

I have a python app that uses GIMP gradients to color images. Other than letting the user choose which GIMP gradient to use, the user doesn't have much more control over the coloring. I'm thinking of how to make it easier to let users edit or create color gradients. Are there preexisting tools for working with creating/editing color gradients (preferably using Python)?

Answer (score 3):

You can get some information about creating gradients from [Here](http://jtauber.com/blog/2008/05/18/creating_gradients_programmatically_in_python/) and it also provides some example code of how to use it.